# Session locale backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am a backpack user and I am trying to change the language of the application.
Through the session I can send another language, but when it enters a route through backpack_url, it gets modified again to english. It may be caused by some middleware. Could you provide me with the middleware or provide some other solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it depends on *how* you've set that language - if you've done that using a middleware, then indeed it might not apply on admin pages, since that middleware is not loaded there.

You could change which middleware admin pages use in your `config/backpack/base.php`, under `middleware_class`. So you could:

A) Add a custom middleware in the base config file, like `App\Http\Middleware\SetLocaleAccordingToX`;

B) Modify an existing middleware to also change the locale. You'll notice in the base config file that, all admin pages go through the `App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin` middleware too (for authorization purposes). You could set the local inside `CheckIfAdmin`.

Personally I think option A is cleaner - one middleware you reuse for both your front-facing and admin-facing pages (if that's your use case).